# Run Openfire on 64bit JVM

Tags: java, memory, jvm, xmpp, openfire

We use OpenFire for XMPP messages. We have some memory issues(OutOfMemoryError), and therefor we would like to increase memory. I know how to increase memory using VM options and we were able to increase memory to 1.5Gb on a 32bit VM. but larger values do not seem supported

We use a 32bit VM, since it appears 64bit VM's are not supported on OpenFire. However there are rumours some people got it working. But everytime I try a 64bit VM I get an error message stating that a 32bit VM was not found

I tried this solution: https://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-1331
But that doesn't work on newer openfire versions

My question: Is there anyone out there that was able to run OpenFire on a 64bit VM, if so, how?

Comment: 1.5GB for an XMPP server seems rather excessive.  I think you're trying to fix a symptom instead of finding the real problem.  Please post a stack trace and describe your situation in more detail, such as whether you are integrating OpenFire into your own code, etc.  There's a significant chance the problem has nothing to do with OpenFire itself and will occur regardless of how much memory is available.   As it stands now your question is not answerable, and therefore off-topic.

Comment: We indeed send (very) large messages over XMPP. We are creating a REST based system now, but until that is finished we would like to increase heap size so OOM occurs less

Comment: What is a "very large" message? How many bytes?

Comment: on average 500k, but they can go up to 20MB

Comment: Did you even bother to do a search? The _first_ hit for "openfire 64 bit java" is https://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-1331

Comment: ofcourse I googled it, and tried it, and doesn't work on newer openfire versions

Comment: XMPP is not designed to convey 20MB messages. You need to consider conveying those out of band.

Comment: @MickaëlRémond thanks you for your input: if that truly is the only good solution to our problem, could you please write that as an answer, then I will accept that answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a direct reply to your memory issue, but XMPP is not designed to convey 20MB messages. You need to consider conveying those messages out of band and use XMPP to negotiate the transfer. You may want to look into XMPP file transfer specification like [XEP-0234: Jingle File Transfer](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0234.html).